# structural vs behavioural design patterns

Tags: design-patterns

I just started reading design patterns and I have some basic doubt and was not clear even after going through many articles. Can someone please explain me following? I have seen many similar posts here but they are not very clear.

1. How did they segregate in to structural and behavioural patterns?
2. Is there any good book to follow?Now I am following Head first design patterns.
3. What is the easy way to remember all these patterns and apply? I thought of remembering UML diagram and concept for each pattern. Do you suggest any other way?

Comment: Head first *is* a good book, and much easier to read than the well known *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*. Anyway, a similar question was asked [on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/124109/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-design-patterns). Quite a while ago, but most books that were good then will still be good. Voting to close this one as off topic because it's broad (three questions in one), opinion based (especially 3) and asking for off-site resources.

Comment: I would like to add that resource requests (including for books) are [off-topic at Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487/22815). The linked question is quite old, and from before resource requests became off-topic at Programmers.

Comment: The best way to understand patterns is practice, practice, and practice :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 1. How did they segregate in to structural and behavioural patterns?

From Gof book

> "Structural patterns are concerned with how classes and objects are composed to form larger structures. "

some structural patterns:

- Adapter
- Decorator
- Facade
- Proxy
- Flyweight

etc

> "Behavior patterns are concerted with algorithms and the assignment of responsibilities between objects.  Behavioral patterns describe not just the patterns of objects or classes but also the patterns of communication between them."

Some behavior patterns:

- Chain of Responsibility
- Command
- Iterator
- Mediator
- Observer
- Visitor

etc

> 2. Is there any good book to follow?Now I am following Head first design patterns.

This question is out of scope of SO since we aren't really supposed to recommend books.

> 3. What is the easy way to remember all these patterns and apply? I thought of remembering UML diagram and concept for each pattern. Do you suggest any other way?

UML diagrams of design patterns are confusing because several patterns have identical or similar enough diagrams that you can't tell them apart. Unfortunately, the easiest way is to just use them enough to just know how to use them.  And keep a Design Pattern book handy to find motivations for the lesser used patterns you don't remember off the top of your head.